# How to pass all string,number,picture value from another java class to anoher class?

Tags: java

Im very new to java code. Im trying to solve on passing value like string, number n picture from class to another class form but im stuck to link another class to class for displaying output. The project is more like complete the survey where the user will need to choose and complete the survey and the result will appear to another form after click the button. Please help me to solve it.

first class:

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class JavaApplication8 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private JLabel pic1, pic2, label1, label2, label3, label4;
    private ImageIcon icon1, icon2;
    private JRadioButton radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4;
    private ButtonGroup mygroup;
    private JComboBox combo1;
    private JButton button1, button2;

    public JavaApplication8(){
        super.setLayout(null);

        //item display
        pic1 = new JLabel(icon1);
        pic1.setSize(350,350);
        pic1.setLocation(20,70);
        pic1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
        add(pic1);

        //logo display
        pic2 = new JLabel(icon2);
        pic2.setSize(200,200);
        pic2.setLocation(20,450);
        pic2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
        add(pic2);

        //Name item selected
        label1 = new JLabel("Item Name");
        label1.setSize(200,40);
        label1.setLocation(500,50);
        add(label1);

        //Pick the optional color
        label2 = new JLabel("Color:");
        label2.setSize(200,40);
        label2.setLocation(500,80);
        add(label2);

        radio1 = new JRadioButton("White");
        radio2 = new JRadioButton("Black");
        radio3 = new JRadioButton("Pink");
        radio4 = new JRadioButton("Yellow");

        radio1.setActionCommand("r1");
        radio2.setActionCommand("r2");
        radio3.setActionCommand("r3");
        radio4.setActionCommand("r4");
        radio1.addActionListener(this);
        radio2.addActionListener(this);
        radio3.addActionListener(this);
        radio4.addActionListener(this);

        mygroup = new ButtonGroup();
        mygroup.add(radio1);
        mygroup.add(radio2);
        mygroup.add(radio3);
        mygroup.add(radio4);

        radio1.setBounds(550, 80, 60, 40);
        radio2.setBounds(640, 80, 60, 40);
        radio3.setBounds(550, 110, 60, 40);
        radio4.setBounds(640, 110, 100, 40);

        add(radio1);
        add(radio2);
        add(radio3);
        add(radio4);

        //Pick LOGO
        label3 = new JLabel("Logo Design:");
        label3.setSize(200,40);
        label3.setLocation(500,140);
        add(label3);

        String[] logo = {"None", "Adidas", "Puma", "Nike", "Batman", "DC", "Facebook", "Youtube", "Android", "Superman", "Twitter", "Radioactive"};
        combo1 = new JComboBox(logo);
        combo1.setBounds(50,50,100,20);
        combo1.setLocation(500,170);
        combo1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        add(combo1);
        combo1.addActionListener(this);

        //Total price
        label4 = new JLabel("Total Price:");
        label4.setSize(200,40);
        label4.setLocation(500,160);
        add(label4);

        //button buy
        button1 = new JButton("Purchase");
        button1.setSize(100,30);
        button1.setLocation(500,200);
        add(button1);
        button1.setActionCommand("b1");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                NewJFrame obj = new NewJFrame();
                obj.MyWido();
            }
        });

        //button back
        button2 = new JButton("Back");
        button2.setSize(100,30);
        button2.setLocation(610,200);
        add(button2);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int logoshow, logodisplay, result;


        if(e.getSource() == combo1){
            int logodis = combo1.getSelectedIndex();

  result = method1(logodis);         

            switch(logodis){
                case 0:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon();
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("adidas.jpg");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("puma.jpg");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("nike.jpg");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("batman.png");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("dc.jpg");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("facebook.png");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("youtube.jpg");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 8:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("android.jpg");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 9:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("superman.png");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 10:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("twitter.jpg");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;

                case 11:
                    icon2 = new ImageIcon("radioactive.jpg");
                    pic2.setIcon(icon2);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if("r1".equals(e.getActionCommand())){

        }

        if ("r2".equals(e.getActionCommand())){

        }

        if("r3".equals(e.getActionCommand())){

        }        
    }

    public static void MyGUI(){
        JFrame MyWindow = new JFrame("Showing Label");
        MyWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyWindow.add(new JavaApplication8());
        MyWindow.setSize(800,750);
        MyWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MyGUI();

    }

    public static int method1(int logodisplay){
        int logoshow;

        logoshow = logodisplay;
        return logoshow;

    }

}
```

second class:

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Azrai
 */
public class NewJFrame extends JPanel {

    private JLabel label3, wardrobe;
    private ImageIcon icon1;

    public NewJFrame() {
        super.setLayout(null);

        wardrobe = new JLabel(icon1);
        wardrobe.setSize(350,350);
        wardrobe.setLocation(20,70);
        wardrobe.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
        add(wardrobe);

        label3 = new JLabel();
        label3.setSize(200,40);
        label3.setLocation(500,100);
        add(label3);

        JavaApplication8 test = new JavaApplication8(logoshow);
        test.Show();
    }

    public static void MyWido() {
        JFrame Frame2 = new JFrame("Result");
        Frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame2.setSize(800, 750);
        Frame2.add(new NewJFrame());
        Frame2.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MyWido();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For passing values between classes you can add arguments to the constructor of your class, in the same way you would do for a method.

For example you can refactor the construct of the NewJFrame  class like this:

```
public NewJFrame(String myString, int myInt) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: if i add argument in newjframe, its the class1 also need to be add the argument too at NewJFrame obj = new NewJFrame;?

Comment: Yes. In my example you create a new object this way: `NewJFrame obj = new NewJFrame("some string", 99)`;